# Predict next date of incident using R from dates only

Tags: r, survival, prediction

I have name of incident and date, which is not univariate. I need to do prediction/forecasting for upcoming event based on date. I have tried to do it by using average of date difference between consecutive dates. Also tried to do it by using `rollmean` for latest trend.

```
> head(df1$Date)
[1] "2014-01-20" "2014-01-22" "2014-03-10" "2014-04-10" "2014-04-15" "2014-04-15"
```

I was wondering is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "is not univariate"? It seems to me you only want to make your predictions from the dates, which is univariate. The event name data you seem to be ignoring?

Comment: Yes.I want to make prediction just from date only.

Comment: Can you further explain whether your task is classification or regression or something else?

Comment: What kind of events? Could there be seasonality? weekday effects? Other calendar effects (easter)? ...

Answer (score 0):

Check out a technique called 'landmarking' in survival analysis. Basically looking at the historical data from an ex-ante perspective. If you are trying to forecast two quarters ahead from now. Then you looking at the historical data in a way that the covariates information is is two quarters ahead of the results.

Comment: Could you possibly expand your answer or give some references?

Answer (score 0):

Working with day differences between dates.

If you know the data to be stationary and not auto-correlated (i.e. it doesn't trend, and the occurrences happen roughly at a constant rate), then consider modelling it as an arrival process. I.e. fit a Poisson distribution to it. Then E(X) gives you your forecast, and you can also show confidence intervals and all that jazz.

If you know the data to be auto-correlated and/or not to be stationary and you're not particularly experienced in time-series forecasting, then I'd suggest starting out with [exponential smoothing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_smoothing). R has very easy to use packages for this. If you want confidence intervals, you can fit a distribution to the residuals or bootstrap them.